# PostgreSQL : Encrypting the data directory on PostgreSQL-9.4

Tags: postgresql, encryption

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which we are using PostgreSQL-9.4 running on Debian Linux as our database. I was able to find library Jasypt which can be used for encrypting and decrypting specific columns. However, is it possible to encrypt the data directory which is decrypted in runtime. I stumbled upon EcryptFS, but as far as I know it doesn't work with PostgreSQL, any alternative options? Thank you.

How much performance impact are we looking at?

We are open to upgrading PostgreSQL version if necessary.

*Update*

I also came upon [this](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgres-and-transparent-data-encryption-tde) link, although it doesn't provide how to tell the PostgreSQL service script to connect to Postgresql. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Use an encrypted file system.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ : Our system is already installed, and we cannot do reinstallation at this point to encrypt the entire FS. Our root runs on an SSD so we dont even want to move it to another directory.

Comment: There is another option, if you have enough disk space to temporarily house a copy of the database. You could create a file that houses an encrypted loopback mounted filesystem & mount it in the Postgres data directory. Hacky, but it'd work. Personally I'd take the downtime hit & either repartition or reinstall

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ : Where will this loopback mounted filesystem will be from? It also doesn't seem like a permanent solution. If we get the data directory encrypted, we won't have to worry about a loopback system anymore. Any ideas about he link posted. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with the loopback mounted FS suggested by @Philᵀᴹ.  I've used that method before. If you ever encrypt the whole file system, then boot with the encrypted file system mount the loop back encrypted file system and copy over the data directory. That's all there is to it.

Comment: You should be scarred of databases that do this for you.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ : Seems like I have to try this out atleast. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thank you. Edit :  Our root runs on an SSD so we dont even want to move it to another non-ssd disk.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ : Debian linux 9.0. 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux